# How to get format details of a drive in Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt4, file-format

I am working on an app where I need to display the file format of a drive(NTFS or FAT32). Now I did a little research and found that there is no Qt API which can make it easy for me to grab the format detail. So I came across a windows API which made it possible for me to get the format detail when I connect the drive(External or Internal) and run the application on windows.
Here is the code:

```
TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
DWORD serialNumber = 0;
DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;
DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;

LPCWSTR path = deviceData->m_strPath.utf16(); //deviceData->m_strpath gives me the drive path

if (GetVolumeInformation(
    path,
    volumeName,
    ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),
    &serialNumber,
    &maxComponentLen,
    &fileSystemFlags,
    fileSystemName,
    ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))
{
         newData.strFileSystem = QString::fromUtf16(fileSystemName);
}   

    QList m_SDInfoList;
    m_SDInfoList.append(newData);
```

Is there a way I can get the same Format detail when I run my Qt app in MAC operating system? A MAC API that can help me to get the file format. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You would Need to make use of the underlying system-calls. OS X is based in Unix (BSD) in particular. So you can make use of the underlying Unix System-calls to get Information. 
As OS X is entirely POSIX compliant use the POSIX System calls. Look [here](http://www.makelinux.net/books/ulk3/understandlk-CHP-10-SECT-1) for an overview and [here](http://cplus.kompf.de/posixlist.html) for the file-System calls.
As Cocoa and Objective-C are mainly Used for pure OS X Applications, they are of no Big use for you.

Comment: I just came across [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html) and I am still not able to find the correct method.

Comment: You are providing as link to a large article, what bothers you there?

Comment: Its all about FSEventStreams which is something I am not looking for.